# Can I use `job_manager` to get memories for 3 parts of the experiment?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Here's part of the code I'm working on:

```
all_circuits = []
for _ in range(100):
    all_circuits.extend([quanc_z,quanc_x,quanc_y])
all_circuits = transpile(all_circuits, backend=backend)
MExperiments = job_manager.run(all_circuits, backend=backend, shots = 1024)
results = meas_filter.apply(MExperiments.results())
memory_z = results.get_memory()
memory_x = results.get_memory() 
memory_y = results.get_memory()   # Question
```

I have a list of quantum circuits `all_circuits` composed of the repeating circuit sequence `quanc_z(,x,y)` and I'm trying to run them using qiskit [job_manager](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager.html). I applied the readout error mitigation to the results and I want to [get the memories](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.html#qiskit.result.Result.get_memory) of each quantum circuit in `all_circuits`, and combine the memories with the same label `z,x,y` on their associated circuits. I wonder is there a way I can get the memory for each circuit that I submitted in a bundle using job manager? Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it has more to do with extracting data from the result and not so much with job manager.

Method 1, use the circuit index. If your circuits are always in the z, x, y order, then you can do something like

```
memory_z = []
memory_x = []
memory_y = []

for i in range(len(all_circuits)):
    mem = results.get_memory(i)
    if i % 3 == 0:
        memory_z.append(mem) # or however you want to combine them
    elif i % 3 == 1:
        memory_x.append(mem)
    else:
        memory_y.append(mem)
```

Method 2, assign metadata to each circuit and use that to differentiate individual result data, something like

```
quanc_z.metadata = {"tag": "z"}
quanc_x.metadata = {"tag": "x"}
quanc_y.metadata = {"tag": "y"}

combined = results.combine_results()
for i, r in enumerate(combined.results):
    if r.header.metadata["tag"] == "z":
        memory_z.append(results.get_memory(i))
    ...  # repeat for the other 2
```

2 additional things to note:

1. You need a lower measurement level or `memory=True` in your `job_manager.run()` to get memory data. See the [`get_memory` doc](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.html#qiskit.result.Result.get_memory) for more details.
2. Measurement correction fitters in qiskit-ignis, if that's what you're using, usually takes a `Result` object as an input. Job manager, on the other hand, returns a `ManagedResults` object. But you can use the `combine_results()` method to convert a `ManagedResults` to a `Result`:

```
managed_result = job_manager.run(...).results()
result_to_fitter = managed_result.combine_results()
```

This `combine_results()` was needed in method 2 above because `ManagedResults` doesn't have the `results` attributes.